# Can't keep extjs dataview multiselection when navigating between windows

Tags: extjs, focus, multi-select, dataview, selectionmodel

I have implemented an `Ext.view.View (xtype: dataview)` with ExtJs 5.0 that supports multiselection.

When I navigate away from the view to another desktop window (or browser tab), then navigate back to it, the selected items are reset and only the next to last item stays selected.

By debugging I found that this is caused by a `focusenter`, then `navigate` event, which is triggered by and belongs to the framework.

This problem occurs with IE, Opera and Chrome, but not(!) with Firefox, which keeps the selection.

Here is a fiddle that reproduces the problem (there is no nice style to show the selected items, but the header bar shows the number of selected items).

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/e6k

Any ideas how to prevent the automatic deselection?

Comment: Have you tried running your code against 5.1 beta? There has been a lot of changes and fixes in that area since 5.0.1.

Comment: I have ended up trashing the whole selection model and implementing selection by myself.

Comment: This bug was indeed fixed in 5.1.0.107.